# How to chain multiple dispatch actions one after the other in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to chain multiple dispatch actions one for the other, by this order:

1.updateCart(dispatch,cartProducts ,loggedUser) - with redux-thunk.

after finishing fetching data, im dispatching actions by order:

2.dispatch(logoutReset()))

3.dispatch(logoutSuccess()))

4.then a refresh - window.location.reload())

but doesnt wait for dispatch to finish first before moving on so it keeps messing up.
i have tried many ways, with await or promises but didn't succeed.

i would like to learn from you guys, how to do it properly.

**Component Navbar**:

```
const handleLogout = async() => {  
        try{
            await  updateCart(dispatch,cartProducts ,loggedUser)
            .then( ()=> dispatch(logoutReset()))
            .then( ()=> dispatch(logoutSuccess()))
            .then( ()=> window.location.reload());
        }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
        }
    };
```

**Actions** (updateCart) redux-thunk:

```
export const updateCart = async (dispatch, selectedProduct, loggedUser) => {
 
  dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_CART });

  try {
   await userRequest.put(`carts/` + loggedUser.id, {
      userId: loggedUser.id,
      products: selectedProduct
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response)
    dispatch(returnErrors(error.response.data, error.response.status));
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you add console.log and check what order by now?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain right, it goes in order but every dispatch takes time, the problem is that he does not wait until dispatches ends its continue without wait for a dispatch to finish, i assume

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, posing if anyone will need it some day.

If you want to do something after dispatch finish, just put useEffect and the parameter that is updated after the dispatch, so after the dispatch and update you can do what you need to do.
very simple approach

```
const handleAddClick = () => {
   dispatch(addToCart({selectedProduct:item,quantity}))
}
```

so after dispatch is finished cartProducts is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
 updateCart(dispatch,cartProducts ,loggedUser)
}, [cartProducts])
```